# insert into with multiple rows not working

Tags: php, sybase

i can't make this insert into work. can someone tell me where i'm doing wrong?

```
$id_application = 1;
foreach ($array_account as $rows) {
    $e_mail = $rows["EMAIL"];
    $pwd = $rows["PWD"];
    $salt = $rows["SALT"];

    $values = "(" . $e_mail . ", " .$pwd . ", " .$salt .  ", " . $id_application . ")";  
    $query = "INSERT INTO DBNAME..ACCOUNT (EMAIL, PWD, SALT, ID_APPLICATION) "
    . " VALUES " . $values;
    $result = sybase_query($query);    
}
```

these are the errors that iget:

```
Column names are illegal. (severity 15, procedure N/A
The identifier that starts with '...' is too long. Maximum length is 30
The name '...' is illegal in this context. Only constants, constant expressions, or variables 
allowed here
```

i'm able to insert a single row in sybase central like:

```
insert into DBNAME..ACCOUNT (EMAIL, PWD, SALT, ID_APPLICATION)  
select EMAIL, PWD, SALT, 3 from ACCOUNT  where ID = 10 go
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Do this $values = "('" . $e_mail . "', '" .$pwd . "', '" .$salt .  "', '" . $id_application . "')";
```